# Firebase Push Notification | Cloud Messaging | FCM http v1

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once 'google-api-php-client--PHP7.4/vendor/autoload.php';

$title = "title";
$body = "body";
$devicetoken = "*****device_token****";

function getGoogleAccessToken(){

    $credentialsFilePath = 'service-account.json'; 
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFilePath);
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');
    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    return $token['access_token'];
  }



function sendFCM($title, $body, $devicetoken) {

  $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/***project_name*****/messages:send';

  $headers = array (
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . getGoogleAccessToken(),
    'Content-Type:application/json'
  );

  $notifData = [
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $body,
    'click_action' => "OPEN_NOTIFY_PAGE",

  ];

  $apiBody = [
    'notification' => $notifData,
    'token' => $devicetoken];

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($apiBody));

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  print($result);

  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;
}
sendFCM($title, $body, $devicetoken);

?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST [https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\`](https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token%5C%60) resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."} in /var/www/html/*****/''''''/google-api-php-client--PHP7.4/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/*****/''''''/google-api-php-client--PHP7.4/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(69): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create() #1 /var/www/html/*****/''''''/google-api-php-client--PHP7.4/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(204): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}() #2 /var/www/html/*****/''''''/google-api-php-client--PHP7.4/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(153): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler() #3 /var/www/html/*****/''''''/google-api-php-client--PHP7.4/vendor/guzzlehttp/pr in /var/www/html/*****/''''''/google-api-php-client--PHP7.4/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 113

I am trying to migrate my FCM from the legacy to http v1. I already follow the docs here, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1, downloaded the Firebase admin SDK and installed google API for PHP 7.4 (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client). However, its not working as expected and I have been trying days to make it working. Can someone point out what I did wrong here?

As a side note, I need to send notification from the web to the user android device. The device token generated and saved in the database. I am still learning so please bear with me.

Comment: Hi, maybe could be a clock problem on your server, you neet to sync it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056381/google-client-invalid-jwt-token-must-be-a-short-lived-token. Your code seems to be ok, I did it the same thing in php environment for my clients with http/2 and multiple tokens https://stackoverflow.com/a/76545442/5596834

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing with you how I solved this problem.

**I'm using Laravel 10 for this demo**

First you need to install [Google Auth Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php) with composer

```
composer require google/auth
```

Generate your Firebase Account Json Credentials : [Credentials Generation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlwWR.png)

Copy your Firebase Project ID which is on the Json you downloaded or on your Firebase Account General Settings

Save your json credentials somewhere in your project in secure place.

**Now use this snippet and adapt it for your usage**

```
<?php
namespace App\CustomClass;

use App\Models\Configuration;
use Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials;
use Google\Auth\HttpHandler\HttpHandlerFactory;

class FireBasePushNotification
{

private $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID_HERE>/messages:send';
private $scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
private $token;

public function __construct()
{
    $config = Configuration::first(); // I stored my json token in database

// Provide the path where you stored the json token, in my case, I stored it in database        
$creadentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials($this->scope, $config->firebase_service);
    $this->token = $creadentials->fetchAuthToken(HttpHandlerFactory::build());
}

public function to($device, $body, $title = "My favorite App")
{
    $data = [
        'token' => $device,
        'title' => $title,
        'body' => $body
    ];

    return $this->send($data);
}

public function send($data)
{
    $headers = [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->token['access_token'],
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];

    $fields = [
        'message' => [
            'token' => $data['token'],
            'notification' => [
                'title' => $data['title'],
                'body' => $data['body']
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $fields = json_encode($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

}

I hope this can help you and help other people at the same time